# Increase number of background workers processing at once

Tags: c#, .net, backgroundworker

I am writing a piece of C# .NET software which spawns a bunch of Background Workers. All of the workers immediately go into the "IsBusy" state, however, only 8 are ever processing through their DoWork method at once.

Is there a way to increase how many run at any one time?

This is how the code spawns the Background workers:

```
      foreach (RESTObjectPrintFile t in printFilesList)
      {
          BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
          bgWorker.DoWork += BgWorker_DoWork;
          bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;

          bgWorkerList.Add(bgWorker);

          bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(t);
      }
```

Comment: Can you share a piece of your code? Which framework, is it ASP.NET Core, or a Worker Service? Maybe a WPF project? Perhaps you have 8 logical cores.. hard to say

Comment: I'd imagine you have an 8 core machine? *Is there a way to increase how many run at any one time?* get a CPU with more cores

Comment: @Liam Ah...I do, yes. Is that a hard limit? Seems a little peculiar to have 1 thread: 1 core?

Comment: You can maybe use async/await to utilise the cores more effectively but that depends on whether your processing is CPU or IO bound.

Comment: *Seems a little peculiar to have 1 thread: 1 core* if that code is blocking then it won't release the core to do anything else.

Comment: In that case we will need to see a [mcve] so we can repro what you are seeing.

Comment: @mjwills No need, the provided answer resolved the issue and reduced overall processing time. Clever things these modern processors, but thanks for your pedantry.

Comment: If the answer helped you, it is because the task scheduler is conservative in adding new threads to the thread pool. It would _eventually_ allow more than 8 tasks - but it increases the pool (relatively) slowly.

Comment: @mjwills How slowly, because it was pinned at 8 threads for several minutes...

Comment: Several minutes is certainly a surprise. Hard to say more without a [mcve]. ;) How did you determine it was pinned to 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(20, 20);
```

Also check this article
http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Optimizing_the_Thread_Pool

At the bottom it says:

> The default value is one thread per core.

Comment: Yep, this allows more workers to enter the "DoWork" function and begin processing. Early benchmarking shows a demonstrable reduction in overall processing time